# ngrok points homepage links to localhost

Tags: wordpress, ngrok

I'm using ngrok to share a locally developed Wordpress site with a client. Everything works fine, except that all links to my home directory go to `localhost:8888` instead of the ngrok URL.

I've got this in my `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_SITEURL',  'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME',  'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you also please share your web server virtual host please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I'm running `localhost:8888` through MAMP, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use something like that no need to insert http

```
define('WP_SITEURL',  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME',  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: Approved your edit above. This still doesn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Same as before. Whereas most links go to `555.ngrok.io/something/or/other`, links to my home page go to `localhost:8888` instead of the expected `555.ngrok.io`

Comment: Actually, I reverted to my original above. Removing 'http://' causes all styling (including on admin pages)  to disappear on my actual local copy.